# Flipping animation similar to the unread count of the home screen

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm looking for a Windows Phone control (or source code) in order to have a counter similar to the one showing the unread count for SMS and mail in the home screen. When the value changes from 2 to 5 for example, we have various animations showing briefly 3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use `Reactive Extension`.

First you need `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive` and `System.Observable` references.

In my xaml page, I defined a `TextBlock` named `NumberTextBlock`. Also I created a `Storyboard` that animates the appearance of the `Text` by modifying its `ScaleY`.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="NumberTextBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock x:Name="NumberTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

In my code-behind, I used a method from `Rx` called `GenerateFromTime()` which adds a time dimension to generated sequence. `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)` here is the delay between each number.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var getNumbers = this.GetNumbers(10);

        getNumbers.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(ChangeNumberTextBlock);
    }

    private void ChangeNumberTextBlock(int number)
    {
        this.NumberTextBlock.Text = number.ToString();
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }

    private IObservable<int> GetNumbers(int total)
    {
        return Observable.GenerateWithTime(0, i => i <= total, i => i, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), i => ++i);
    }
```

You can read more about `Rx` from [here](http://programmerpayback.com/2010/03/11/use-silverlight-reactive-extensions-rx-to-build-responsive-uis/) and [here (Silverlight TV)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-80-Reactive-Extensions).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I love the answer above, but obviously that solution will only work inside a running application.  Currently there is no way to replicate on a Front Screen tile the same animation behaviour as the Mail Tile. Best you can do is to push several images at the tile from a background agent but it wouldn't be as smooth as the Frameworks capabilities.

Comment: I'm not trying to have it on a custom tile, but inside my app. I'm going to see if I can combine the solution of Xin with other storyboards...