# Thread Sleep in for cycle doens't work wp7

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, timer

I have a problem with this piece of code. I need to make a pause of two seconds to see the images. So I put the thread to sleep, but it doesn't work. I need to wait two seconds until I pass to the next value of `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < media_count; i++)
{
    if (type_by_order[i].ToString().Equals("video"))
        Play_Graphics(name_file_by_order[i]);
    if (type_by_order[i].ToString().Equals("image"))
        ImageReadDecode(name_file_by_order[i]);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong? This doesn't work on windows phone 7?

Comment: Can you explain the behavior that you observe? For example, does it ignore your sleep? Or is it waiting for too long?

Comment: waiting for to long.. and then show all the process..

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea, I just wanted to let you know you need to provide more information for people to try to solve your problem. My next suggestion would be to tag your question with the language your code is in (is that Java?). That way, you attract more people to your question.

Comment: Are you trying to pause for two seconds after you start each media item, or pause for two seconds _after it finishes_?

Comment: Never sleep on the UI thread.  Use a timer.

Comment: i am trying to pause two seconds after start each media item.

Comment: I gave you a better answer but you chose not to take it, and that's why now you're having this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408474/make-slide-show-wp7/8410389#8410389

Answer (score 2):

As Hans points out, You are sleeping on the UI thread. This will prevent the UI from updating until the complete for loop is done. Make sure you sleep in the background and then update on the UI Thread. Here is and pseudo code example

```
  BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bgw.DoWork += (sender, e) = {
     for loop {
        Deployment.Current.Thread.BeginInvoke(() => {
            ImageReadDecode
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }
  }
  bgw.RunAsync();
```

Note that using BeginInvoke doesn't garantee that your images are added/loaded in order at the same time. It pushes it on the UI thread and lets the UI thread determine when it will add it.

Hope this makes some sense. There are more then enough example on stackoverflow on how to handle UI thread and background thread.